# Smart contract fees paid from another wallet

Tags: smart-contract

When using smart contract and creating transaction, current wallet/user pays for fees.
Example of transaction:

- burn NFT
- min NFT
- burn native assets

In my situation, my customers have their own wallet (nami #whatever) but is there any chance I can use a company wallet to pay fees instead of them?

Naive idea:

- customers should have some ADA: unfortunately I cannot go forward with it
- granting customers some ADA will allow them to spend them on something else!~

Basically I would have love the idea to have several wallet involve in a single transaction (multisig) but I do not find any relevant solution.

Maybe a different pattern should be think of?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitively possible, provided every paying wallet sign the transaction. To do this with `cardano-cli`, you have to build the raw transaction as usual, involving the use of different UtxO coming from different wallets.

`cardano-cli transaction build ... -> tx.raw`

Then, every involved wallet has to sign separately. For this you have to use

`cardano-cli transaction witness --tx-body-file tx.raw ... -> tx.wit_x`

And finally you have to collect all individually signed `tx.wit_x` parts and assemble them into a single transaction

`cardano-cli transaction assemble --witness-file tx.wit_0 --witness-file tx.wit_1 ...`

Comment: Thanks.
Interesting, if I told you I really want to use smart contract with PAB and Nami would you say it is a dead end (at least for now)?

Comment: I never tried to go for multi-sig with Nami (or ccvault, or others), so I'm not completely sure. However, the CIP 30 that defines the standard API to interface with them (https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip30/) seems to allow that thanks to partial signature. The difficult part will then to setup the required protocol to collect all the partials and to reassemble them into a single final transaction. You will need to use the cardano serialization lib for that purpose. So, definitively not a dead end.